# How to reference an attribute of a tkinter button which is inside of a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list, tkinter, attributes

I'm making a calculator program and am creating the buttons to go in the calculator's interface.  I create all buttons using one for loop initially, and then want to reconfigure certain buttons to change their colour and command.  Is there any way to reference an attribute such as the "text" attribute of a button inside of a list?  For example, if button index has a text attribute of "+" or "-" or "/" or "*" reconfigure colour to red.

The current code I have to do this is very inefficient as it requires each button to be referenced by index individually.  If possible I would like to reference by an attribute and not just by index number.  Algorithm in question can be found below.

```
#Method that creates calculator buttons, appends them to a list and packs them into the grid.
    def create_number_buttons(self):
        button_characters = "789*456/123-0.=+"
        i = 0
        self.button_list = []
        for row_counter in range(2,6):
            for column_counter in range(4):
                self.button_list.append(Button(root, bg="#11708e", fg="white", activebackground="#11708e", pady=25, padx=35, text=button_characters[i], font=("Helvetica", 16, 'bold')))
                self.button_list[i].grid(row=row_counter, column=column_counter, sticky="NSEW")
                self.button_list[i].configure(command = lambda c=button_characters[i]: self.num_press(c))
                i += 1
        #Reconfigures the specific buttons.
        self.button_list[3].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[7].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[11].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[13].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[14].configure(command=lambda: self.calculate_answer(), bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[15].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
```

Thanks for your help!

Full code below :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
#Import so that I'm able to use regex to remove leading zeroes from the equation string when performing the calcultion.
import re

#Class to support logic of calculator, used for functionality and math operations.
class CalculatorFunctions:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.answer = 0

   #Command called if a number button is pressed.
    def num_press(self, num):
        new_input = num
        self.text_box.insert(self.value_position, new_input)
        self.value_position += 1

    #Command that clears everything in the calculator's entrybox.
    def clear_screen(self):
        self.text_box.delete(0, END)

    #Creates a message-box popup to display relevant author information.
    def show_author_button(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Author", "Devin, August 2018")

    #If the eval function returns a syntaxerror or a zerodivision error this command is called.
    #Makes an error message popup box.
    def error_popup(self):
        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please edit your code and calculate again.  Common errors include dividing by 0 and including too many decimal points in one number.")

    #Uses the eval function to calculate entered string in calculator.
    def calculate_answer(self):
        errormessage = "SyntaxError"
        try:
            #Removes leading zeroes from the start of digits but not after a decimal point. 
            self.answer = eval(re.sub(r"((?<=^)|(?<=[^\.\d]))0+(\d+)", r"\1\2", self.equation.get()))
        except (SyntaxError, ZeroDivisionError):
            self.error_popup()

        self.answer = eval(re.sub(r"((?<=^)|(?<=[^\.\d]))0+(\d+)", r"\1\2", self.equation.get()))
        #Appends answer to list of values able to be inserted into calculator entry.
        self.accepted_values.append(str(self.answer))
        self.text_box.delete(0, END)
        self.update_entry_with_answer()

    def update_entry_with_answer(self):
        self.text_box.insert(0, self.answer)

    #Removes the last character in the entry field.
    def backspace(self):
        current = str(self.text_box.get())
        new_input = current[:-1]
        self.accepted_values.append(new_input)
        self.text_box.delete(0, END)
        self.text_box.insert(0, new_input)


    #Checks for valid input
    def testVal(self, entered_value, modifytype):

        #Checks if text wanting to be inserted into the entryfield is valid.
        if modifytype == '1': #insert

            operators_and_d_point = "/*+-"
            current_string = str(self.equation.get())

            if entered_value == ".":
                if current_string[-1] == ".":
                    return False

            #If the last character entered was an operator, don't allow another operator or decimal point to be added to the entry box.
            if entered_value in operators_and_d_point:
                if current_string == "":
                    if entered_value == "-" or entered_value == "+":
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False

                if current_string[-1] in operators_and_d_point:
                    if entered_value == "+" or entered_value == "-":
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False


            if entered_value in self.accepted_values:
                return True


        #Accepts all attempts to remove text from the entryfield.
        elif modifytype == "0":#delete
            return True

        return False

#Class to create widgets for the calculator GUI.
class CalculatorGUI(CalculatorFunctions):

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.value_position = 0
        self.create_calculator_widgets()
        root.bind("=", lambda event: self.calculate_answer())
        self.accepted_values = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "+", "-", "*", "/", "."]

    #Method called to create widgets associated with the calculator.
    def create_calculator_widgets(self):
        self.create_text_box()
        self.create_number_buttons()
        self.create_clear_button()
        self.create_author_button()
        self.create_backspace_button()

    #Creates entry field, contents of the entry field stored as textvariable.
    def create_text_box(self):
        self.equation = StringVar()
        self.text_box = Entry(root, justify=RIGHT, validate="key", textvariable=self.equation, font=("Helveitca", 16), borderwidth=15)
        #Uses the tkinter entry box's "validatecommand" to check for valid input, method found in above class.
        self.text_box['validatecommand'] = (self.text_box.register(self.testVal),'%S','%d')
        self.text_box.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, ipady=10, sticky="WE")

    #Method that creates calculator buttons, appends them to a list and packs them into the grid.
    def create_number_buttons(self):
        button_characters = "789*456/123-0.=+"
        i = 0
        self.button_list = []
        for row_counter in range(2,6):
            for column_counter in range(4):
                self.button_list.append(Button(root, bg="#11708e", fg="white", activebackground="#11708e", pady=25, padx=35, text=button_characters[i], font=("Helvetica", 16, 'bold')))
                self.button_list[i].grid(row=row_counter, column=column_counter, sticky="NSEW")
                self.button_list[i].configure(command = lambda c=button_characters[i]: self.num_press(c))
                i += 1
        #Reconfigures the specific buttons.
        self.button_list[3].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[7].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[11].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[13].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[14].configure(command=lambda: self.calculate_answer(), bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")
        self.button_list[15].configure(bg="#d14302", activebackground="#d14302")


    def create_clear_button(self):
        clear_button = Button(root, bg="#302e2e", fg="white", text="AC", font=("Helvetica", 12, 'bold'), pady=10,  command=lambda: self.clear_screen())
        clear_button.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="WE")


    def create_backspace_button(self):
        backspace_button = Button(root, bg="#302e2e", fg="white", text="Backspace", font=("Helvetica", 12, 'bold'), command=lambda: self.backspace())
        backspace_button.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="NSEW")

    def create_author_button(self):
        author_button = Button(root, bg="#302e2e", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 12, 'bold'), text="Info", command=lambda: self.show_author_button())
        author_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="NSEW")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    calc = CalculatorGUI(root)
    root.title("Calculator")
    #Ensures the GUI window containing the calculator is unable to be resized, the 0,0 represents the x,y of resize allowed.
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you believe your way is inefficient? It is better than having to loop through the list, get the attribute, check its value, and then modify the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you want to configure a group of widgets to an identical style save the
widget references in a dedicated object(list or dictionary).
You can then loop through those specific references applying the identical configuration.
For example if you wanted to apply red to only the operator buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
numberframe = tk.Frame()
numberframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
button = {}
names = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
         'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'zero')
for num, name in enumerate(names):
   temp = tk.Button(master=numberframe,
                    text=(num+1)%10)
   temp.grid(column=num%3,
             row=num//3,
             sticky='nsew')
   button[name] = temp
operators = {}
operator_frame = tk.Frame()
operator_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
operation = (('divide', '/'), ('multiply', '*'),
             ('subtract', '-'), ('add', '+'))
for name, sign in operation:
   temp = tk.Button(master=operator_frame,
                    text=sign)
   temp.grid()
   operators[name] = temp
# example individually configure by the reference name.
button['seven'].configure(fg='red')

# example configure by group
for item in operators:
   operators[item].configure(fg='red')
master.mainloop()
```